# Free forum software with a good spam protection

Tags: spam-prevention

About a week ago I had to pull the plug on my PhpBB forums because spam had reached totally unmanageable levels:

The database contained well over 300,000 spam topics & messages, for a total of 8 Gb of junk. None of it was displayed on the website, as the forum was on a strict moderation queue, so there was no point to it, but the volume was such that moderation was plain impossible.

Now, I am considering my options for a new forum.

My requirements are:

- PHP or easy to install on a typical
- LAMP hosting Free Really good spam protection.
- Easy to customize & integrate in my website
- Reasonably stable & fast
- Easy to manage

PhpBB was good, but the SPAM problem was so bad that the forum never had a chance to really get anywhere.

I have been looking around at similar questions, but there are very little info regarding the quality of their anti-spam features.

Comment: Why don't just install an anti-spam plugin to phpBB?

Comment: @Aircule: Do you know any that really works? If so, please post it as an answer. Based on the volume of spam, I need an anti-spam feature that would take care automatically of at least 95% of all spam. One problem with phpBB is that it is so popular that hackers went to great lengths to crack it. I would rather have something less popular that people don't attack as much to start with.

Comment: To those who closed this question: my answer (below) did involve PHP programming.

Comment: @reinerpost: yes. Closing the question is not right, IMHO, because the choice of a BB requires adding it to the code base, and that code base will have to be maintained, so in the end, it's a programming matter. I contacted the people who voted to close the question. 2 of them replied that they thought it belonged to serverfault. One of them agreed that he closed the question too hastily. The others did not reply yet. Either way, thanks for your answers. They are useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have added reCAPTCHA to a phpBB forum *for user registration* and additionally run reCAPTCHA plus a very simple blacklist filter handwritten into the phpBB code on posting attempts from *unregistered* users, and the spam levels are minimal.

Comment: reCAPTCHA for posting is really annoying.

Comment: Thanks. What were your spam levels before you implemented reCAPTCHA? And what does it like if you don't use reCAPTCHA for posting? That feels a little much.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: the fraction of rejected postings is consistently above 95%, but I can't easily see how much of that is due to reCAPTCHA.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tools to stop spam in and around PhpBB.

- Require registration to post
- Require email validation to register
- Use a CAPTCHA on the registration form
- Use [Akismet](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=1340275) to filter posts coming through (there are a lot of other mods than the one I linked to).
- Use moderate-first-post (can't remember if it's built in or an add-on)

But if you're looking for something faster and perhaps a little simpler, [PunBB](http://punbb.informer.com/) is popular and a fork of it, [FluxBB](http://fluxbb.org/) is growing in popularity (since the PunBB brand was bought by "the man").

They are a lot faster and lighter on resources but you do trade in quite a lot of community resources, plugins, and built-in features for that.

I implemented FluxBB in [a client's site](http://almerimarlife.com/), [as viewable here](http://almerimarlife.com/forum/) just to show you that it can be fairly tightly integrated into a site's design. In this case the main site is a Wordpress install.

---

Just noticed your comment on your opening post. I don't think there are any plug-ins, importers or anything really that will automatically cut down **existing** spam.

Most spam is very similar. Unless you've been targeted by multiple spammers, you might be able to write a little PHP script to look for known spam signatures and delete them (and their users) automatically.

This should get you back to a point where you can manually moderate quite quickly.

Comment: All of these measures were on except for Akismet. Apparently, the problem is that PHPBB CAPTCHA is too weak. For FluxBB, it looks like its approach to security is pretty weak. No CAPTCHA on registration, links get posted on the forum without nofollow... unless I am missing something, it doesn't look very secure at all.

Comment: PHPBB has *other* CAPTCHA modules you can use if you're not happy with the standard one, just as PunBB and FluxBB have plugins that provide CAPTCHA-on-registration (see the registration page of my example site). There are also plugins and hacks for no-follow, even akismet. All those things can be achieved on PhpBB, PunBB and FluxBB. Google will set you free!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [punbb](http://punbb.informer.com/)? It has good spam and xss protection.

Comment: Thanks, I had a quick look. The captcha looks weak. Do you run a forum based on punbb?